# IE only error on internal network only

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype, internal

I just recently launched our new website, works as it should, never had an issue with it during the development process internally.  Once actually deployed to the domain however to replace the old site we starting having ONLY internal users complain about a security alert message popping up in IE (mostly IE8) on each page. I have verified that this is NOT an issue outside of our local network.  The alert dialog states:

[image]

Regardless of choosing 'Yes' or 'No' the page will render the exact same. This happens on each page, however once you choose 'Yes' it won't show for that page until you close/open the browser.

I have researched this quite a bit and here are a few things I suspect:

1. The Doctype...  I have set this to be html5 and is as shown

[image]

2. The Broswer Mode and Document Mode... I can make the error appear by changing both of these to 8 in the IE Dev Tools. It seems that as long as I can keep everything in IE9 mode the error doesn't display.
3. The Meta tag for the modes... I have it set to IE-edge, chrome-1 (see above screenshot)
4. Nothing on the site is under https:// so I know that isn't a cause.
5. There isn't any cross-domain js or anything crazy going on at all.

A note, the organization I work at is large, and we manage our own DNS internally. This error did not appear until I flipped the site onto the new domain.  So it worked fine while under development at the domain www.dev-mysite.com.... but once I changed it over to www.mysite.com is when the alerts immediately began to appear.

I know that I can eliminate this error by changing zone permissions on each users machine, but that isn't an option.  I appreciate any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured this out.  It was due to a reference I had to a CSS3 media queries .js file hosted on Google.  It was in a IE conditional statement, thus the IE only warnings :).  Removing this file altogether was the only solution for my scenario that worked.

Rock.